# How to improve the performance of needleman -wunsch algorithm in CUDA

Tags: algorithm, cuda, gpu

I need an advice on how optimizing my implementation of the Needleman-Wunsch algorithm in CUDA.

I want to optimize my code to fill the DP matrix in CUDA. Due to the data dependence between matrix elements (each next element depends on the other ones - left to it, up to it, and left-up to it), I'm filling anti-diagonal matrix elements in parallel as follows:

```
__global__ void alignment_kernel(int *T, char *A, char *B, int t_M, int t_N, int d) {
  int row = BLOCK_SIZE_Y * blockIdx.y + threadIdx.y;
  int col = BLOCK_SIZE_X * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;

  // Check if we are inside the table boundaries.
  if (!(row < t_M && col < t_N)) {
    return;
  }

  // Check if current thread is on the current diagonal
  if (row + col != d) {
    return;
  }

  int v1;
  int v2;
  int v3;
  int v4;
  v1 = v2 = v3 = v4 = INT_MIN;

  if (row > 0 && col > 0) {
    v1 = T[t_N * (row - 1) + (col - 1)] + score_matrix_read(A[row - 1], B[col - 1]);
  }
  if (row > 0 && col >= 0) {
    v2 = T[t_N * (row - 1) + col] + gap;
  }
  if (row >= 0 && col > 0) {
    v3 = T[t_N * row + (col - 1)] + gap;
  } 
  if (row == 0 && col == 0) {
    v4 = 0;
  }

  // Synchronize (ensure all the data is available)
  __syncthreads();

  T[t_N * row + col] = mmax(v1, v2, v3, v4);
}
```

Nevertheless, one obvious problem of my code is that I do multiple kernel calls (code bellow). Until now, I don't know how to use threads to process the anti-diagonal synchronously without doing that. I think this is a major problem to reach a better performance.

```
// Invoke kernel.
  for (int d = 0; d < t_M + t_N - 1; d++) {
    alignment_kernel<<< gridDim, blockDim >>>(d_T, d_A, d_B, t_M, t_N, d);
    //CHECK_FOR_CUDA_ERROR();
  }
```

How can I process the anti-diagonal in parallel and, maybe, using shared memory to increase the speedup?

Beyond this problem, is there any way to do the back trace step of the needleman-wunsch algorithm in parallel?

Comment: Have you looked at the nvbio library?  It has all sorts of DP algorithms for local and global alignment, tuned for CUDA.  Written by NVIDIA engineers. http://nvlabs.github.io/nvbio/alignment_page.html

Answer (score 1):

I am currently working on a parallel implementation of the Needleman Wunsch algorithm as well (to use in a genome mapper). Depending on how many alignments you will be doing, it may be more efficient to do a single alignment per thread.

However, here is a [publication](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/292977570_Speed_Up_Needleman-Wunsch_Global_Alignment_Algorithm_Using_GPU_Technique) that performs a single alignment in parallel (on a GPU). The novelty of their approach is that it does not generate the matrix sequentially, by rather diagonally. They don't talk about how they backtrack in their publication. They send the matrix back to the host after it is generated, then they perform the backtrack using a CPU. I think that backtracking on the GPU would be terribly inefficient due to branching.